# Database not deleted, it just keep on duplicating the insert query while on second click it is supposed to delete the value

Tags: php, sql

it is duplicating the same query instead of deleting the value and l want it to check if the clicked then it delete the value if it is one or insert if zero

```
if(isset($_POST['notification']))
{
  try {
      $stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO notification(user_id, action) VALUES (?, 1)");
      $stmt->execute([$user_id]);
      $message = 'You will receive an email';
    } catch (\PDOException $e) {
      if ((int) $e->getCode() === 23000){
       $stm2 = $pdo->prepare("DELETE FROM notification WHERE user_id = ?");
       $stm2->execute([$user_id]);
       $message = 'You will not receive an email for notification';
    }else {
        $error = true;
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: found the solution thank you

Comment: Feel free to [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) here! It might help others who face the same issue.

Comment: okay thanks l will

Comment: SO is for helping each other; please post your answer otherwise your question does not help anyone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the solution I came up with.

```
if(isset($_POST['notification']))
{
  if ($notification == 1)
  {
    $stm2 = $pdo->prepare("DELETE FROM notification WHERE user_id = ?");
    $stm2->execute([$user_id]);
    $message = 'You will not receive an email for notification';
  }
  else {
      $stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO notification(user_id, action) VALUES (?, 1)");
      $stmt->execute([$user_id]);
      $message = 'You will receive an email';
    }
}
```